# Canonical lift of Elliptic curve in Smart attack

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, cryptography, p-adic-number-theory

### Smart attack details

Given some curve $E/\mathbb F_p$ with order $p$, lift it to $E_0=E/\mathbb Q_p$ and define the subgroups of $E/\mathbb Q_p$: $E_r=\{(x,y)\in E/\mathbb Q_p|v_p(x)\leq-2r,v_p(y)\leq-3r\}\cup\{\infty\}$. We have the following isomorphism of groups: $\frac{E_0}{E_1}\cong E/\mathbb F_p$ and $\frac{E_1}{E_2}\cong\mathbb F^+_p$, which the first isomorphism given by reduction mod $p$ last isomorphism given by $\psi:(x,y)\to -\frac x{py}\pmod p$

Assume that $kP=Q$ in $E/\mathbb F_p$, typically if we are only given $P,Q$, findiing $k$ is computationally hard. However since $E/\mathbb F_p$ is anomalous, Smart attack gives us a simple solution:

After lifting the curve to $E/\mathbb Q_p$, let $\tilde P,\tilde Q$ be the lifted points of $P,Q$ respectively, then we have $p\tilde P,p\tilde Q,k\tilde P-\tilde Q\in E_1$ since $E/\mathbb F_p$ is of order $p$. Furthermore, since $k\psi(p\tilde P)-\psi(p\tilde Q)=p\psi(k\tilde P-\tilde Q)=0$, we get that $k=\frac{\psi(p\tilde Q)}{\psi(p\tilde P)}\pmod p$, which is pretty simple to compute.

### When the attack fails

The proof fails if $pP\in E_2$, since we get $k=\frac00$. This is noted in the [Smart attack](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s001459900052)'s paper, where he notes that for 'canonical lifts', such points exist, and 'canonical lifts' occur at a frequency of $\frac1p$. An example of such a lift can be found at the crypto SE question [why the Smart attack fails for a particular lift](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/70508/61171).

> My question is why does hitting the canonical lift cause the attack to fail(which was answered in the comments), and why does it happen with a $\frac1p$ probability?

Some examples of 'canonical lifts':

The curve, $y^2=x^3+3x+5$ over $\mathbb F_7$, has the following 'canonical lifts' when lifted to $\mathbb Q_7$, for $m,n>0,m,n\in\mathbb Z$ and $p=7$:

$$y^2=x^3+\left(3+0p+mp^2\right)x+\left(5+3p+np^2\right)$$
$$y^2=x^3+\left(3+1p+mp^2\right)x+\left(5+2p+np^2\right)$$
$$y^2=x^3+\left(3+2p+mp^2\right)x+\left(5+1p+np^2\right)$$
$$y^2=x^3+\left(3+3p+mp^2\right)x+\left(5+0p+np^2\right)$$
$$y^2=x^3+\left(3+4p+mp^2\right)x+\left(5+6p+np^2\right)$$
$$y^2=x^3+\left(3+5p+mp^2\right)x+\left(5+5p+np^2\right)$$
$$y^2=x^3+\left(3+6p+mp^2\right)x+\left(5+4p+np^2\right)$$

In general(as far as I can tell by direct computation), one finds $p$ 'canonical lifts' mod $p^2$ for any anomalous curves, which satisfies the $\frac1p$ probability that Smart gave.

### About the 'canonical lift'(from comments)

If the Frobenius endomorphism $f\in\text{End}\left(E/\overline{\mathbb F_p}\right)$ lifts to a endomorphism $\tilde f\in\text{End}\left(E/\overline{\mathbb Q_p}\right)$, then this is the 'canonical lift' that Smart is referring to, which is less strict than requiring $\text{End}\left(E/\overline{\mathbb F_p}\right)\cong\text{End}\left(E/\overline{\mathbb Q_p}\right)$. Since $\left|E/\mathbb F_p\right|=p$, the dual of $f$, $f^*$ has kernel $E/\mathbb F_p$ and is separable, which implies the dual of $\tilde f$, $\tilde f^*$, has a kernel of order $p$, which is precisely the $p$-torsion elements of $E/\mathbb Q_p$, and is the torsion group $\left(E/\mathbb Q_p\right)_\text{tors}$ of this curve, hence $E_0\cong E_1\times\left(E/\mathbb Q_p\right)_\text{tors}$, hence $pE_0=pE_1$ and $p\tilde P\in E_2$, causing the attack to fail.

Comment: @reuns hm yea but i cant quite see how this connects canonical lift to $pP\in E_2$, maybe theres some other way to define canonical lift that makes it trivial but im not seeing it right now
(oh oops this was typed before the edit lemme read)

yea i've seen that point of all points being all in $E_1-E_2$ or $E_2$ 

hm yea but I'm wondering what exactly makes a canonical lift cause all points to go in $E_2$

Comment: @reuns I dont think $E_0$ has any torsion points really? it's more of for $P\in E_0$, $pP\in E_2$, these are the points I'm interested in(well they are torsion in $E_0/E_2$)

Comment: Sorry, can you check this : The formal group law and formal logarithm says $E_1\cong \Bbb{Z}_p$ is torsion free and Hensel lemma gives that $E_0\to E$ is surjective, so $E_0/E_1\cong E$. Since $|E|=p$, the question is then to determinate the structure of $E_0$ from $(E_0)_{tors}$, if the torsion is trivial then $E_1=pE_0$ and the attack always works. If $(E_0)_{tors}$ is non-trivial then $E_0=E_1\times (E_0)_{tors}$ and $pE_0=pE_1$ and the attack  always fails (the case $p\nmid |E|$ is different as multiplication by $|E|$ is separable so Hensel lemma lifts $E_{tors}$ to $(E_0)_{tors}$)

Comment: The bad case in Smart paper is the so-called canonical lift, which means that the Frobenius $f\in End(E(\overline{\Bbb{F}}_p))$ lifts to an endomorphism $f_0\in End(E_0(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p))$, then $|E|=p$ implies that the dual isogeny $f^*$ is separable so that, with Hensel lemma, $\ker(f^*)=E$ lifts to $\ker(f_0^*)= (E_0)_{tors}$.

Comment: @reuns hm i dont really get why $E_0=E_1\times(E_0)_{tors}$ and doesnt hensel lemma only lift to a point that is equivalent under $mod p$, so there is no guarantee that it is torsion

Comment: Once $|(E_0)_{tors}|=p$ then $E_1$ torsion free gives $E_0/E_1=(E_0)_{tors}$ so $E_0=\bigcup_{A\in (E_0)_{tors}} A+E_1=E_1\times (E_0)_{tors}$. And once we have that $f^*$ is separable $\in End(E)$ we apply Hensel lemma to the algebraic equation $f_0^* A=O$

Comment: @reuns Ahh ok so my understanding now is: If the frobenius isogeny lifts to a endomorphism and since the dual isogeny has kernel order $p$, the lifted dual isogeny is separable, hence by hensel lemma we get the kernel is $(E_0)[p]=(E_0)_{tors}$ with order $p$, so $E_0$ splits to $(E_0)_{tors}\times E_1$ and $pE_0=pE_1$ that sounds good

Comment: It remains to understand the $1/p$ probability claim, I'm not sure if I know how to do it but my intuition tells me that once the lift $\bmod p^2$ works it works $\bmod $ all $p^k$ thus in the $p$-adics independently on the equation chosen for $E_0$

Comment: @reuns For that you can transform it to Z_p with [x:y:z]->[x:z:y] and take it mod p. The p^2 terms and above doesnt matter. With that there are p^2 possible lifts but not too sure how to prove that p lifts are the so-called 'canonical' lifts